# Mask a UIImage programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I'm trying to mask a `UIImage` by programmatically creating a `CGImageRef mask` and applying it through `CGImageCreateWithMask()`. This is my approach:

```
- (UIImage *)imageByMaskingHalfImage:(UIImage *)image {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((CGSize){image.size.width, image.size.height}, NO, image.scale);

    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width / 2, image.size.height));

    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(CGRectMake(image.size.width / 2, 0, image.size.width / 2, image.size.height));

    UIImage *maskImage  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGImageRef maskImageRef = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskImage.CGImage),
                                                CGImageGetHeight(maskImage.CGImage),
                                                CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskImage.CGImage),
                                                CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskImage.CGImage),
                                                CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskImage.CGImage),
                                                CGImageGetDataProvider(maskImage.CGImage),
                                                NULL,
                                                NO);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithMask(image.CGImage, maskImageRef);
    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(maskImageRef);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return image;
}
```

When previewing the `maskImage`, I can see it correctly being rendered: half of the image is black and half of it is white. However, the resulting masked `image` remains unchanged, the whole image is visible.

I've read the documentation and I cannot find the problem. There must be some silly error in my code, or I'm misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I masked the image in the shape A

Create a method which gets the mask shape, in my case shape A:

```
  -(void)shapeA:(CGRect)frame :(UIImageView*) testView {

    ////  Drawing
    UIBezierPath* textPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
    [textPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 284.92, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 243.03)];
    [textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 230.48, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 84.58)];
    [textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 172.62, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 243.03)];
    [textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 284.92, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 243.03)];
    [textPath closePath];
    [textPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 205.09, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 31.36)];
    [textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 260.02, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 31.36)];
    [textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 390.14, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 390)];
    [textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 336.92, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 390)];
    [textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 300.54, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 282.58)];
    [textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 158.7, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 282.58)];
    [textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 119.88, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 390)];
    [textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 70.08, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 390)];
    [textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 205.09, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 31.36)];
    [textPath closePath];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = textPath.CGPath;
    shapeLayer.strokeColor   = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.fillColor     = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    [testView.layer setMask:shapeLayer];

}
```

The above method is declared in NSObject file called SHapeLayer.

and call this method in your view controller:

```
-(void)callShape{

CGRect temp=self.imageView.bounds;
ShapeLayer *sl=[[ShapeLayer alloc]init];
  [sl shapeA:temp :self.imageView];
}
```

and now call this method `[self callShape];` before you load an image.

Comment: Thanks, but if possible, I'd prefer to directly mask the `UIImage` (ideally through the use of `CGImageCreateWithMask()`) rather than masking the `UIImageView`.